# Elasticfox won't connect - EC2 error for DescribeRegions

Tags: amazon-ec2, firefox-addon

I recently started getting an error using Elasticfox.

> EC2 responded with an error for DescribeRegions
>
> Request ID:
>
> Fault Code: Request Error
>
> Details: Please check your EC2 URL 'https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' for correctness, or delete the value in ec2ui.endpoints using about:config and retry.

I've followed the directions to clear the endpoints value in about:config but still get this error. Some of my colleagues get the same error, while others do not. My user has full permissions for our ec2 resources. Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are generally supposed to relate to programming, see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Your question should be better off on http://superuser.com/ than here.

Answer (score 0):

Your point about ec2ui.endpoints helped me solve the issue. (I was recently having the same issue.)

Make a new  ec2ui.endpoints with a string value of ({}) and its solved.

ps: Hate the latest stackoverflow user fad of closing questions. (Not moving but closing. )